# How to get data from parsedJSON reactJS

Tags: json, reactjs, response

I'm setting up a basic WebApp here using ReactJS. Right now I can add data to my database using POST request no problem, the thing, my backend response sends me a JSON with all the data that I passed and the _id in the database. I need to get this _id and save it in my state so I can pass it along to the next URL in my WebApp. That's the code for my POST request :

```
  SubmitClick(){

    if (this.state.password !== this.state.reTypepassword){
      alert('Passwords do not match. Please check your data !');
    } else {
      //console.log(this.state); //debug only
      fetch('http://localhost:4000/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          //'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQ=',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: this.state.email,
          first_name: this.state.first_name,
          last_name: this.state.last_name,
          personal_phone: this.state.personal_phone,
          password: this.state.password
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON._id))
      .catch(error => alert('Check your data', error))
      .then(this.props.history.push('/get')) // change page layout and URL
    }
    console.log(this.state.id); //debug to see if the _id is saved in my state
  }
```

Here is my constructor:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      email:'',
      first_name:'',
      last_name:'',
      personal_phone:'',
      password:'',
      reTypepassword:'',
      id:''
    }
  }
```

I tried calling a function after `parsedJSON` that used `this.setState()`, using `function(parsedJSON){this.state.id : parsedJSON._id}`. I tried with a new function like this:

```
  changeID(parsedJSON){
    this.setState({id : parsedJSON._id})
  }
```

and changing the `.then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON._id))` to `.then(parsedJSON => this.cahngeID(parsedJSON))`. But none of then worked...

I left the code with `.then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON._id))` so can make sure that I can see this value, and in my console it`s printed perfectly.

Here is a example of the response send by my backend:    `{"email":"testing@gmail.com","first_name":"TESTER","last_name":"Testing","personal_phone":"(55) 2020-5252","password":"12345","_id":"5a27f511cd7d7a0db8ab65b9"}`

How can I get the "_id" from my response?

Comment: What was the syntax for your original this.setState() call? Also, I think you'll want to move your debug to see if the _id was saved to the state inside your then(), where it's at currently will not give you the correct result.

Comment: changeID(parsedJSON){
    this.setState({id : parsedJSON._id})
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not touch the `this.state` property directly. React will throw an error if you do this because React needs to know when `this.state` has been updated so that it can keep track of the changes. It cannot do this if you manipulate the property directly. That's why we have [`React.Component#setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). The "shallow" version is the most commonly used, where you pass an object that will be merged into your state. For example, the following:

```
.then(parsedJSON => this.setState({ id: parsedJSON._id }))
```

is equivalent to:

```
Object.assign(this.state, { id: parsedJSON._id });
```

except that React gets to keep track of when the state is updated.

Note that `setState` is also asynchronous and takes a callback as the second parameter. You can [read more about that here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

As per the comment below, [this other Stack Overflow question was helpful to the OP (Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: So instead of using `.then(parsedJSON => this.setState({ id: parsedJSON._id }))` I have to use `Object.assign(this.state, { id: parsedJSON._id });` ? I got the following error :  `Line 40:  'parsedJSON' is not defined  no-undef`.
If i use `.then(parsedJSON => Object.assign(this.state,{ id: parsedJSON._id }))` nothing changes actually.

Comment: hey Alex, using the information that you offered I searched in the internet how to immediately change my state before moving on with the code, an then the callback function in the setState shows up. I found this question here that helped me to fix my problem, together with your info: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your constructor add this line of code:

```
this.SubmitClick = this.SubmitClick.bind(this);
```

because JavaScript does not bind the instance value of 'this' to our methods.

Comment: I added this to my constructor, and tried the codes that I mentioned in the question, but nothing really changed... Do I have to make more changes in the code?